# can i parse JSON in a mongo db query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Imagine I had the following documents in my collection

```
{'name':'toothpaste','price':'{"currency":"USD","value":17}'}
{'name':'laptop','price':'{"currency":"EUR","value":1080}'}
```

and I want to query for documents whose price-currency is USD and price-value is less than 100 in one query.
Please remember that the price columnn is holding a JSON string and it is not an embedded object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a custom function in your query, check out the [$function operator of the aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/). This is a new feature of Mongo >= 4.4 (thanks @Victor)

As for your query, you can do something like this:

```js
db.items.find({"$expr": { "$function": {
  body: function(price) {
    const parsed = JSON.parse(price);
    return parsed.currency === "USD" && parsed.value <= 100
  },
  args: ["$price"],
  lang: "js"
}  }})
```

One thing I found out that you must save the JSON string with double quotes (which you are doing correctly) in order for JSON.parse() to work correctly

Test the code using the mongo Web shell [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/getting-started/)

```js
>>> db.items.insertMany([ { "name": "toothpaste", "price": '{"currency":"USD","value":17}' }, { "name": "laptop", "price": '{"currency":"EUR","value":1080}' } ])

>>> db.items.find({"$expr": { "$function": {
  body: function(price) {
    const parsed = JSON.parse(price);
    return parsed.value === 17
  },
  args: ["$price"],
  lang: "js"
}  }})
```

Comment: New as of 4.4. Neat!